# Função timer não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a biblioteca Sweet Alert e ao mostrar uma mensagem desejo que ela fique na tela apenas por determinado tempo e em seguida obviamente desapareça, de acordo com a documentação eu posso utilizar uma função da própria biblioteca, no caso acionaria ela adicionando o parâmetro `timer` (mensurado em ms) ao criar o *alert*. Segue meu código:

```
swal({
    title:'Inserção concluída!',
    text: 'Inserção concluída com êxito.',
    type: 'success',
    timer: 2000
})
```

Na demo do *site* tudo funciona corretamente, mas ao executar o mesmo código não obtenho o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Não mostra nada. Um detalhe é que estou utilizando o framework AngularJS, poderia ele estar interferindo nisto?

Comment: Eu já falei que não tem, e eu sei o que é.

Comment: Ok, e tens os ficheiro `.js` e `.css` que o Sweet Alert precisa carregados?

Comment: Sim, ele está funcionando, apenas a função timer que não está.

Comment: É possivel reproduzir isso num jsFiddle? se não é dificil conseguir ajudar mais...

Comment: O "erro" não seria a falta de um ponto-e-vírgula (;) ali no final da chamada de `swal`?